# Need to use dynamic params with Uplink to warp an API that returns paginated results

Tags: python, api

I am attempting to use [Uplink](https://pypi.org/project/uplink/) to wrap the BitBucket API. When I try to get all of the projects in my server with `rest/api/1.0/projects` it returns a list of projects along with a 'nextPageStart' that needs to be set in the params to get the next set of results. I went to the documentation to try to find a way to fix this issue and found that params is, "a decorator that adds static query parameters for API calls." I am attempting to find a way to pass the params dynamically.

```
from uplink import Consumer, get, params
import json

class BitBucket(Consumer):
    """A Python client for the BitBucket API"""

    @params({"start": 0})
    @get("rest/api/1.0/projects")
    def get_projects(self):
        """Get the public projects"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bit_bucket = ButBucket(base_url="<my base url>")

    projects = bit_bucket.get_projects()
    print(projects.json())
```

By giving my correct base URL, I can get the first page of results with the above code. I now need to modify `@params({"start": 0})` or set the request params another way. How can I dynamically send the `nextPageStart` I get from the response to the next request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `uplink.Query` for dynamic params

```
from uplink import Consumer, get, params, Query
import json

class BitBucket(Consumer):
    """A Python client for the BitBucket API"""


    @get("rest/api/1.0/projects")
    def get_projects(self, start: Query('start')):
        """Get the public projects"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bit_bucket = ButBucket(base_url="<my base url>")

    projects = bit_bucket.get_projects()
    print(projects.json())
```